# How do I create rules in “.htaccess” for redirecting URLs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want following redirects to happen

```
example.com --> www.example.com/abc
www.example.com --> www.example.com/abc
example.com/abc --> www.example.com/abc
example.com/anyRubbish --> www.example.com/abc
```

But I'm confused with the difference between RedirectCond and ReWriteRule and RewriteBase, 'L' and 'R in [L,R 301] etc.

I'm writing rules for Apache Server.

Comment: Information about L, R NC could be found here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond ℅{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} !^/ABC
 RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/abc℅{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Here is a short explanation:

The first condition `rewrite cond ℅{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]` checks if the http host header string isn't starting with `www` . The condition returns true if host host value is **example.com** .
The second condition `RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} !^/ABC` tests  the Uri . Checks if the Uri isn't **/ABC** . . This returns true if the URL is **example.com/foobar** and returns false if the URL is **example.com/ABC** 
`OR` flag tells mod-rewrite to execute one of the conditions , if one of the conditions in the above script is met then the rule gets applied.

The RewriteRule `RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/abc℅{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]` is applied according to the conditions , this will rewrite all requests to **www.example.com/ABC**.